# Symfony2 - Listing Comments sorted in DESC order from Post entity

Tags: symfony, post, doctrine-orm, comments

I have Comments setup as ManyToOne/OneToMany to Posts.

And I would like to display all Comments from the Posts in DESC order.

I've already setup a query to list a single post with DESC order yet the comments still display as ASC.

**How can I get the comments to display in DESC order? Doesn't it inherit the way the Posts are being listed out?**

Post query

```
public function findPostsBySlug($slug)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('post')
        ->select('post')
        ->where('post.slug = :slug')
        ->setParameter('slug', $slug)
        ->orderBy('post.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();
}
```

Twig

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
    {%  for comment in post.comments %}
        <article class="comment">
            <header>
                <p>
                <time datetime="{{ comment.createdAt | date('c') }}">{{ comment.createdAt | date }}</time>
                by {{ comment.author }}
                </p>
            </header>

                <p>{{ comment.body | nl2br }}</p><hr>
        </article>
    {%  endfor %}<br>
```

Controller

```
public function showAction($slug)
{
    $post = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Post')
        ->findPostsBySlug($slug);

    if (null === $post) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Post was not found');
    }

    return array(
        'post' => $post
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out, I needed to make another query for Comments and call it in the controller.

```
public function findCommentsForPost($postId)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('comment')
        ->select('comment')
        ->where('comment.post = :post_id')
        ->setParameter('post_id', $postId)
        ->orderBy('comment.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the order directive in annotations

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Comment::class, mappedBy="Post", orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "DESC"})
 */
private $comments;
```